# Different method for parameter estimation auto.arima

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, multivariate-regression

I am trying to fit a multivariate time series with the `auto.arima()` function in R. Since my time series has seasonality I included Fourier approximation and used the following  method proposed by Rob J Hyndman

```
bestfit<-list(aicc=Inf) # Select K value
for(i in 1:25)
{
fit<- auto.arima(y, xreg=fourier(y, K=i), seasonal=FALSE) 
 if(fit$aicc<bestfit$aicc)
   bestfit<-fit
 else break;
}
```

Aside from adding more variables that will increase estimation, it fits well based on the methods used by the package. In my understanding estimation is done by "CSS-ML". However, I am forecasting demand of products where the error is measured by a pinball loss function similar to:

\begin{align}
L(q_a, y) = \begin{cases}(1 - a/100) (q_a - y), & \text{if $y< q_a$};\\
a/100 (y - q_a), & \text{if $y\ge q_a$};
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I would like to estimate my parameters by minimizing a pinball loss function like the one above for the
`auto.arima()` function. It does not specifically has to be this function, but minimizing a loss function in combination with the `auto.arima()` function would be great. Does anyone has a suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think auto.arima() (or any of the standard forecasting packages in R) can be used directly with pinball loss. You would have to write your own functions to do so.

However one workaround for your problem is to generate forecasts using auto.arima(), and then use the forecast intervals to calculate the quantiles, which would allow you to simulate a forecast generated using pinball loss.

See [this blog post by Rob Hyndman for details](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/quantile-forecasts-in-r/).